# python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.4m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have created a python virtual environment using *virtualenv*, after activating it, I can see where is Python installed in my shell as following:

```sh
(virtualenv-test) bash-4.1$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python2.6-config /usr/bin/python
/usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib64/python2.6 /usr/X11R6/bin/python2.6
/usr/X11R6/bin/python2.6-config /usr/X11R6/bin/python
/usr/bin/X11/python2.6 /usr/bin/X11/python2.6-config
/usr/bin/X11/python /usr/include/python2.6
/usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

Also I can see what python version I'm using:

```sh
(virtualenv-test) bash-4.1$ which python
/data/virtualenv-test/bin/python
```

However, after typing python, I got the following error message:

```sh
(virtualenv-test) bash-4.1$ python
python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.4m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What can be the underlying reason?

Answer (score 74):

Try adding the python3.4's lib path to the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

First find out the lib path of python3.4 (depends on how you installed python3.4)

For me it was: `/opt/python361/lib`, then add it to environment variable like so:

```sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/python361/lib
```

**P.S.**
I came across a similar problem while using `virtualenv` with `python3.6`, and I fixed it like so:

- First, append `include <lib path of python3.x>` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` (Something like: `include /opt/python361/lib` or `include /usr/local/lib`)
- Then, activate the new configuration by running `sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v`.

Comment: 2. worked for me. Could you point me in the direction of a good resource to understand why this works? thanks.

Comment: 1. did the trick on Red Hat (no virtual env). My path was /opt/local/lib (I built python from source with --enable-shared in the call to ./configure and it printed out the path of the shared files.

Comment: First answer worked for me but then when I used gunicorn I got the same error in which case the P.S. solution did it.

Comment: in centos 7 it is ```export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib```

Comment: @AbhilashSinghChauhan this worked for me on Amazon Linux 2

Answer (score 34):

Another way is adding `LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"` in configure, for example

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
```

`/usr/local/lib` is the path where `libpython3.*.so` files are in

Comment: This worked for me. Python 3.7.4 under CentOS. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me building and installing python-3.8.2 on ubuntu 14.04.6

Comment: I received the following error when trying this solution: `./python: symbol lookup error: ./python: undefined symbol: __gcov_indirect_call_callee`  I'm removing these flags and am going to try @williezh's solution.

Answer (score 21):

For Python 3.6, it was fixed by

```
sudo apt-get install libpython3.6-dev
```

Comment: python 3.6 isn't available in my repos.  I'm on Jessie.  Yay!

Comment: And also for Python 3.9: `sudo apt-get install libpython3.9-dev`

Answer (score 13):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=[your python path to libpython3.4m.so]
```

`libpython3.4m.so` is under your python source from which you built it.

Put it in your `.bashrc` to set it at login automatically.

I can't force virtualenv to 3.4 on my machine but you can see that under `lib` of your virtualenv there's just a bunch of symlink to your local python installation. I guess `libpython3.4m.so` is fetched by one of those.

Comment: To add to this answer for Linux users, if you cannot find where it may be located (perhaps due to multiple installations of Python), use the locate/find command.

Answer (score 6):

For me, `libpython3.6m.so.1.0` was in the folder where I downloaded Python source (`~/Python3.6.9`).

I simply did:

```
sudo cp ~/Python3.6.9/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/
```

and:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.6
```

Answer (score 5):

This one worked for me.

```sh
cd ~/
vim .bashrc
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/miniconda/envs/python3.6/lib/
```

Comment: old question, add versioning and why this works to improve answer quality. Otherwise it helps trigger down-voters or bot labeling question "low quality answer". End of Review. Welcome and enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Kudos to above, For python 3.X you can fix this issue with:

```
sudo apt-get install libpython3.x-dev
```

No need to any changes to environment path manually.

Comment: Not on ububtu 20.04

Answer (score 3):

If you are manually installing another `python3` or `python`,

e.g: python3.6,

the active files(e.g: python3.6, python3.6m, python3.6m-config) are located at `/usr/local/bin`,

the library files(e.g: python3.6, libpython3.so, libpython3.6m.so.1.0) are located at `/usr/local/lib`,

While you do not configure any environment before `make & make install`,

Now you need to add the load_library_path(`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) of python3.6,

if you are using `zsh`, just:

```
cd ~

vim ~/.zshrc
```

Add the below code to `~/.zshrc`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/
```

Just use `:wq` to save and quit the configuration file of zsh,

also, you need to active the hnewable `.zshrc`:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

then try:

python

If you use `bash`, just:

```
cd ~

vim ~/.bashrc
```

And the below code to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/
```

Just use `:wq` to save and quit the configuration file of `bash`,

also, you need to active the newable `.bashrc`:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now, for your turn!

First, you need to found out where `libpython3.4m.so.1.0` is?

From you asked and told, I guess `libpython3.4m.so.1.0` is located at

`/data/virtualenv-test/lib/` because I saw your python is located at

`/data/virtualenv-test/bin/python`.

Second, add that loading library path to your `bash`'s configuration file `~/.bashrc`:

```
cd ~

vim ~/.bashrc
```

Use `i` to enter `VIM` editing state, and add the below code to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/data/virtualenv-test/lib/
```

Use `:wq` to save and quit `.bashrc`, and active the newable `.bashrc`:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Third, test your installed `Python`.

All in all, you could change the upsatirs `/data/virtualenv-test/lib/` to

yours(where `libpython3.4m.so.1.0` is).

END!

Answer (score 1):

On python 3.8, I resolved this by deleting the virtualenv directory (`./venv` in my case) and recreating using python's built-in `venv` module installed of the pip-installed `virtualenv`. I'm on arch linux and also first did `sudo pacman -Syu`. Python was originally installed using just `sudo pacman -S python`.

```
$ rm -r ./venv
$ python -m venv venv
$ . ./venv/bin/activate
$ python --version
Python 3.8.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it running by installing the package:

```
sudo apt-get install libpython3.x-dev
```

Comment: not on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by installing `libpython3.X` without the (`-dev`). In your case, it gives:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libpython3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

For Github Actions, this could be worked around by installing the dependency directly, disabling the actions/setup-python cache and using the generic cache action instead:

```yaml
   - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: '3'
    - uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: ~/.cache/pip
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip
    - run: pip install 'mydependency<2'
      shell: bash
    - run: ${{ github.action_path }}/myscript
      shell: bash
```

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora or dnf-based system

```
# dnf search python3.10

=====================================================================
python3.10.i686 : Version 3.10 of the Python interpreter
python3.10.x86_64 : Version 3.10 of the Python interpreter
======================================================================= Name delle corrispondenze: python3.10 =======================================================================
python3.10-debug.i686 : Debug version of the Python runtime
python3.10-debug.x86_64 : Debug version of the Python runtime
python3.10-devel.i686 : Libraries and header files needed for Python development
python3.10-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and header files needed for Python development
python3.10-idle.i686 : A basic graphical development environment for Python
python3.10-idle.x86_64 : A basic graphical development environment for Python
python3.10-libs.i686 : Python runtime libraries
python3.10-libs.x86_64 : Python runtime libraries
python3.10-test.i686 : The self-test suite for the main python3 package
python3.10-test.x86_64 : The self-test suite for the main python3 package
python3.10-tkinter.i686 : A GUI toolkit for Python
python3.10-tkinter.x86_64 : A GUI toolkit for Python
# dnf install python3.10-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

My python binary also had this error while using bazel with the `linux-sandbox` and `--experimental_use_hermetic_linux_sandbox`

This was caused because the binary we were running did not have access to `/dev/`, `/proc`, and `/sys`

After mounting those directories with `--sandbox_add_mount_pair`, it started working