# Error loading shared library libpython3.7m.so.1.0: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/coverage)

Tags: python

I seem to be having issues with my python interpreter. I am getting the following error on my terminal when trying to start the Django webserver:

> 1) Error loading shared library libpython3.7m.so.1.0: No such file or
>   directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/coverage)  2) Error relocating
>   /usr/local/bin/coverage: _Py_UnixMain: symbol not found

Any idea or clues on what I should be looking for in regards to the error above? I am running ubuntu on my system. This problem seems to occur after I started a new Django project.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.4m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333207/python-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpython3-4m-so-1-0-cannot-open)

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a `Path` related issue. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333207/python-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpython3-4m-so-1-0-cannot-open) for solutions on how you can alter the path. Alternatively, you can simply fix the issue the following way:

```
sudo apt-get install libpython3.x-dev
```

This way you won't need to any changes to environment path manually.