# error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.9.so.1.0 Anaconda Python3.9 C embedding

Tags: python, c, linux, anaconda

I have a C script that calls Python, and I've gotten most of it to work properly. However, when I try to run the compiled file, I get the following error:

```
~/Documents/code/test: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.9.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-cdpcz1c5.vwd" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-j5b1thxt.2vz"
```

I am writing this in VS Code and my `tasks.json` file is:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-I${workspaceFolder}",
                "-I/usr/include/glib-2.0",
                "-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include",
                "-I${HOME}/anaconda3/envs/metagenomics/include",
                "-I${HOME}/anaconda3/envs/metagenomics/include/python3.9",
                "-I${HOME}/anaconda3/envs/metagenomics/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-L${HOME}/anaconda3/envs/metagenomics/lib",
                "-L${HOME}/anaconda3/envs/metagenomics/lib/python3.9",
                "-L${HOME}/anaconda3/envs/metagenomics/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu",
                "-lpython3.9",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
"version": "2.0.0"
}
```

And the build command is:

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/gcc -fdiagnostics-color=always -I${HOME}/Documents/code -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I${HOME}/anaconda3/envs/myenv/include -I${HOME}/anaconda3/envs/myenv/include/python3.9 -I${HOME}/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy -g ${HOME}/Documents/code/test.c -o ${HOME}/Documents/code/test -L${HOME}/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib -L${HOME}/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9 -L${HOME}/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.9

Build finished successfully.
```

I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333207/python-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpython3-4m-so-1-0-cannot-open), but it doesn't really help with my question. I am using Anaconda as an environment manager, which shouldn't matter, but I'm not really sure. As shown, I'm including the library "${HOME}/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib" and there is a "libpython3.9.so.1.0" file within this directory. When I use the command: `find ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/ -name libpython3.9.so.*`, I get this result:

```
~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
```

So, anyhow, I'm not sure why the compiled program is not recognizing this file. Could it be a permissions problem? The permissions for that file are: `-rwxrwxr-x`.