# Error loading shared library libpython3.10.so.1.0

Tags: docker, python-3.10

I get the following error

> Error loading shared library libpython3.10.so.1.0: No such file or
> directory (needed by /usr/bin/aws) Error relocating /usr/bin/aws:
> Py_BytesMain: symbol not found

when I'm trying to run the docker image.

this is the dockerfile -

```
FROM node:16.17.1-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add git openssh-client vim python3 py3-pip jq
RUN pip install awscli
RUN apk --purge -v del py-pip

RUN apk add --no-cache yarn

RUN rm /var/cache/apk/*

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
yarn install --frozen-lockfile

COPY . .
RUN yarn build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["sh", "startup.sh"]
```

Please advise how I can resolve this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333207/python-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpython3-4m-so-1-0-cannot-open

Comment: I tried installing libpython3-dev but if failed on build stage.

Comment: Please provide bigger log fragment to see the place where this error happens.

Answer (score -3):

The error came from one sh script which was called in `CMD ["sh", "startup.sh"]`. The script was outdated and was there by mistake, which caused the error.