# VS Code cannot find python libpython3.10.so

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, shared-libraries

I am trying to select a vritual environment as the default interpreter for python in vs code, but this fails. In the terminal I can, without issues run

```
$ <venv_path>/python
Python 3.10.8 (main, Mar 14 2023, 20:30:44) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

or

```
which python
<venv_path>/python
```

after the environment has been activated. Furthermore, in the terminal, I can see that

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
...:/opt/<...>/lib/:...
```

which means that the libraries can be found from the terminal so the python can run. Now the problem. When I try to select `<venv_path>/python` as the interpreter for the opened project, this fails with an error message. In the output window I see the following:

> [Error: Command failed: <venv_path>/python -I /<...>/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.6.0/pythonFiles/get_output_via_markers.py /<...>/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.6.0/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py 
> <venv_path>/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.10.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Which means that vs code was not able to find the library. Why is that and how can I fixt that?

Comment: Can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43623903/18359438) solve your issue? Try adding the python3.10's lib path to the environment variable.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT As I wrote, in the opened terminal, this path is in the lib path environment variable. It seems like the discovery uses a different terminal?

Comment: Have you tried using other virtual terminals? Maybe there's something wrong with this virtual terminal.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT As it turned out (this problem occured on an HPC cluster) there was always a backgroud session still active for my account. A quick `killall -u <username>` killed all sessions and processes running in my name. After logging back in with ssh the problem was resolved.

Comment: I should add that I definitely did log out with VS Code and all other accessible terminals I saw but that was not enough. Something was still holding onto the incorrect `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` value. Only after terminating everything it worked. Also, normally it is not allowed that anything runs in the background when I am not actually logged in. It is unclear to me, why this happened in the first place. Interrupting my network connection should have stopped everything running in my name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out (this problem occured on an HPC cluster) there was always *some* backgroud process still active for my account. A quick killall -u  everything running in my name. After logging back in with ssh the problem was resolved.